# What is the cleanest way to perform a JWT refresh in Android using Kotlin and Volley after a request responds with 401?

Tags: android, kotlin, jwt, android-volley

As the question states I want to see the cleanest way to perform a JWT refresh. What I have found out using Volley is that it responds with `networkResponse` being a null object in case the API responds with a 401 which is apparently a bug in the library. So what I do in case of an error is check whether it is null and in that case try to send a refresh. However after the refresh I should try and repeat the previous request which leads to spaghetti code (or recursion which I'd like to avoid). Is there a clean way to go around this? How would I repeat the exact same last request after refreshing a token?

```
val url = "${Constants.BASE_URL}/autologin"
val request = object : JsonObjectRequest(
    Method.POST, url, null,
    {
        // Something to do if it works
    },
    {
        if(it.networkResponse == null || it.networkResponse?.statusCode == 401)
        // Try refreshing is the condition is true. Then retry this request but this will be messy
    }
){
    @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token"
        return headers
    }
}
RequestSingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request)
```

Comment: Maybe provide some code of what you have working and indicate what is wrong and what you want to fix. "What is the cleanest way to do X" is just asking for opinions, not answers.

Comment: @dominicoder Yeah, sure. Just added the sample code.